# Using one javascript function for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I have several forms for a product order page. Each Item on the page needs to have two prices, one for a one time order, and one for a recurring order.

The code I have is working fine, the problem is a need three javascript functions for each item, which as you can guess will get out of hand fast.

Here is the form for one product:

```
<form id="mangoForm" action="https://ximo365.foxycart.com/cart" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Mango Bash Pack" />
    <input id="mango-price-input" type="hidden" name="price" value="50" />
    <input id="mango-sub-input" type="hidden" name="sub_frequency" value="1m"> 
    <input id="mango-refBy" type="hidden" name="Referred By:" value="Not Specified">

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" onclick="changePriceLowMango()" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe & Save</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="changePriceHighMango()" class="btn btn-default">One Time</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="mangoSubmit()" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit form">Add To Cart</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And her is that forms javascript:

```
function changePriceHighMango() {
   document.getElementById("mango-price").innerHTML = "80.00";
   document.getElementById("mango-price-desc").innerHTML = "Switch to recurring and save up to 35%!";
   document.getElementById("mango-price-input").value = "80.00";
   document.getElementById("mango-sub-input").name = "Frequency";
   document.getElementById("mango-sub-input").value = "Single Order";
}

function changePriceLowMango() {
   document.getElementById("mango-price").innerHTML = "50.00";
   document.getElementById("mango-price-desc").innerHTML = "Recurring Price. Cancel Anytime.";
   document.getElementById("mango-price-input").value = "50.00";
   document.getElementById("mango-sub-input").name = "sub_frequency";
   document.getElementById("mango-sub-input").value = "1m";
}

function mangoSubmit() {
   var mangoName = document.getElementById("distName").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("mango-refBy").value = mangoName;
   document.getElementById("mangoForm").submit();
}
```

What I would like is three functions–one for increasing the price, one for decreasing the price, and one for submitting the form–that will work for each item.  The functions would need to know which forms to change, what the low and high prices are, and what items on that form to update.

Is that at all possible to do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to keep as much as the style and code you have right now, I would just pass all the variable stuff as arguments to a more generic `changePrice` function. As you say, the function *would need to know which forms to change, what the low and high prices are, and what items on that form to update*. So let's create a more generic `changePrice` function like this:

```
  function changePrice(productName, description, price, subName, subValue) {
    document.getElementById(productName + "-price").innerHTML = price;
    document.getElementById(productName + "-price-desc").innerHTML = description;
    document.getElementById(productName + "-price-input").value = price;
    document.getElementById(productName + "-sub-input").name = subName;
    document.getElementById(productName + "-sub-input").value = subValue;
  }

  function productSubmit(productName) {
    var distName = document.getElementById("distName").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(productName + "-refBy").value = distName;
    document.getElementById(productName + "Form").submit();
  }
```

I am assuming that all the form inputs begin with the `productName` and have the same suffixes (-price, -price-desc, -price-input, -sub-input, and -sub-input).

Then you can just change the buttons `onclick` property with a call to those functions with the proper arguments.

```
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" onclick="changePrice('mango', 'Recurring Price. Cancel Anytime.', '50.00', 'sub_frequency', '1m')" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe & Save</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="changePrice('mango', 'Switch to recurring and save up to 35%!', '80.00', 'Frequency', 'Single Order')" class="btn btn-default">One Time</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="productSubmit('mango')" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit form">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
```

Example of a form for a **foo* product:

```
<form id="fooForm" action="https://ximo365.foxycart.com/cart" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Foo Bash Pack" />
    <input id="foo-price-input" type="hidden" name="price" value="50" />
    <input id="foo-sub-input" type="hidden" name="sub_frequency" value="1m"> 
    <input id="foo-refBy" type="hidden" name="Referred By:" value="Not Specified">

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" onclick="changePrice('foo', 'Foo Recurring Price. Cancel Anytime.', '10.00', 'sub_frequency', '1m')" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe & Save</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="changePrice('foo', 'Foo Switch to recurring and save up to 35%!', '20.00', 'Frequency', 'Single Order')" class="btn btn-default">One Time</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="productSubmit('foo')" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit form">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function Mango(action) {
    var mangoprice = document.getElementById("mango-price"),
    mangopricedesc = document.getElementById("mango-price-desc"),
    mangopriceinput = document.getElementById("mango-price-input"),
    mangoprivesubinput = document.getElementById("mango-sub-input"),
    mangorefBy = document.getElementById("mango-refBy"),
    mangoForm = document.getElementById("mangoForm");
    var mangoName = document.getElementById("distName").innerHTML;
    switch(action)
    {
        case 'Low':
            mangoprice.innerHTML = "80.00";
            //... etc LOW PRICE
            break;
        case 'High':
            //... etc HIGH PRICE
            break;
        case 'Submit':
            mangorefBy.value = mangoName;
            mangoForm.submit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Greetings from Vienna